# Audio expo library not pausing audio files

Tags: react-native, expo, audio-player

Trying to learn React Native by working on a project and ran into a blocker.

**Goal**: Trying to create an auto-playing feature where audio files are played continuously one after another when a button is pressed and also can be paused when that button is pressed again.

**Current Progress**: I'm able to get the audios to play continuously one after another without any problem. If you take a look at the screenshot below, the audio file is loaded in "useEffect" and when the button is pressed, it will call the "handlePlayPause" function and the audios will continuously play.

```
const [autoPlayIndex, setAutoPlayIndex] = useState(0);
const [playBackInstance, setPlayBackInstance] = useState(null);
const [clickNum, setClickNum] = useState(0);

const loadAudio = async () => {
  if(autoPlayIndex < data.length) {
    if(data[autoPlayIndex].id == 101) {
      const { sound } = await Audio.Sound.createAsync(require("../assets/zoning.mp3"), {progressUpdateIntervalMillis: 100});
      sound.setOnPlaybackStatusUpdate(onPlaybackStatusUpdate);
      setPlayBackInstance(sound);
    } else if (data[autoPlayIndex].id == 103) {
      const { sound } = await Audio.Sound.createAsync(require("../assets/draymond_green.mp3"), {progressUpdateIntervalMillis: 100});
      sound.setOnPlaybackStatusUpdate(onPlaybackStatusUpdate);
      setPlayBackInstance(sound);
    } else {
      const { sound } = await Audio.Sound.createAsync({uri: data[autoPlayIndex].file}, {progressUpdateIntervalMillis: 100});
      sound.setOnPlaybackStatusUpdate(onPlaybackStatusUpdate);
      setPlayBackInstance(sound);
    }
    if(clickNum % 2 != 0) {
      await playBackInstance.playAsync();
    }
  }

}

const handlePlayPause = () => {
  if(clickNum % 2 == 0) {
    playBackInstance.playAsync();
  } else {
    playBackInstance.pauseAsync()
  }

  setClickNum(clickNum => clickNum + 1);
}

const handleNext = async () => {
  setAutoPlayIndex(autoPlayIndex => autoPlayIndex + 1);
}

const onPlaybackStatusUpdate = async (status) => {
  if(status.isPlaying) {
    const duration = status.positionMillis;
    const length = status.durationMillis;
    const diff = length - duration;
    setTimeRemaining(Moment.utc(diff).format("m:ss"));
  }
  if(status.didJustFinish) {
    handleNext();
  }
}

useEffect(() => {
  if(data.length != 0 ) {
    loadAudio();
  }
}, [autoPlayIndex, clickNum]);
```

**Problem**: The audio files are not paused instantly but they are paused after it's done playing the current audio clip. Not sure exactly why, because I specify to "pauseAsync()" but it seems some sort of async problem or something.

**References**:

- Audio library being used: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/audio/?redirected

Any help on this problem will be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Please post code and not pictures of code, which aren't mobile friendly, aren't searchable, can't be copied and pasted, and don't work well with screen readers.

Comment: @jnpdx Sorry about that. Just updated the question!

Answer (score 0):

I've created a [Snack](https://snack.expo.io/@kartikeyvaish/audio-implementation) for the Implmentation you need.. Hope it helps. Works perfectly for me..

Don't create a `state` variable and store `Audio` instance in it. That is not the right way to implment playlist audio functionality

See you first have to change your `Audio` instance to a `ref`. So that you can `pause/play` from anywhere from the code.

At the top create `sound` variable like this

```
const sound = useRef(new Audio.Sound());
```

Load a audio file like this -

```
  const LoadAudio = async (index) => {
    SetLoading(true);
    const checkLoading = await sound.current.getStatusAsync();
    if (checkLoading.isLoaded === false) {
      try {
        const result = await sound.current.loadAsync(
          Files[index].file,
          {},
          true
        );
        if (result.isLoaded === false) {
          SetLoading(false);
          SetLoaded(false);
        } else {
          sound.current.setOnPlaybackStatusUpdate(UpdateStatus);
          SetLoading(false);
          SetLoaded(true);
          SetDuration(result.durationMillis);
          PlayAudio();
        }
      } catch (error) {
        SetLoading(false);
        SetLoaded(false);
      }
    } else {
      SetLoading(false);
      SetLoaded(true);
    }
  };
```

`Pause` function -

```
 const PauseAudio = async () => {
    try {
      const result = await sound.current.getStatusAsync();
      if (result.isLoaded) {
        if (result.isPlaying === true) {
          sound.current.pauseAsync();
          SetPlaying(false);
        }
      }
    } catch (error) {
      SetPlaying(true);
    }
  };
```

`Play` function -

```
  const PlayAudio = async () => {
    try {
      const result = await sound.current.getStatusAsync();
      if (result.isLoaded) {
        if (result.isPlaying === false) {
          sound.current.playAsync();
          SetPlaying(true);
        }
      }
    } catch (error) {
      SetPlaying(false);
    }
  };
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/28831125)

Comment: @EricSchaefer I've added the explanation and the main reason why this error was occuring.

Comment: @KartikeyVaish Couldn't have asked for a better explanation. Thanks for the quick reply!